# ERR Trap and command substitution

Tags: bash, shell

Running `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eE
trap "echo 'in trap'" ERR
var=$(bad_command)
```

Output is:

```
./test.sh: line 7: bad_command: command not found
in trap
```

Running `test2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eE
trap "echo 'in trap'" ERR
echo $(bad_command)
```

Output is:

```
./test2.sh: line 8: bad_command: command not found
# line with whitespace printed
```

Why is the trap not triggered in `test2.sh`?

Comment: Related: ["Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: In most places in shell the exit status is equal to the last command executed. So the _last_ command executed in `echo $(bad_command)` is `echo` and the command succeeded. No reason to go to trap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference *only* matters which of the commands `var=$(badcommand)` and `echo $(badcommand)` set the incorrect exit code to the shell. As it is clearly evident the second case, `echo` does *not* set the incorrect exit code as it is a separate process running which is capable of setting its own code depending upon its success/failure. Since `echo` which seemed to have exited correctly though it did not have any output to print it printed a code `0` to shell thereby masking the `command not found` error from the command substitution.

Just try for yourself running in shell without the `set -e` and the traps defined

```
var=$(badcommand); echo $?
bash: badcommand: command not found...
127
echo $(badcommand); echo $?
bash: badcommand: command not found...

0
```

The first one fires the trap and the next one doesn't.